# Телеграм-бот не показывает кнопки

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

> Функция должна выкидывать по две кнопки с ссылками на плейлисты в зависимости от выбора пользователя(если физ-мат то на плейлист про физику и математику, если хим-био то на химию и биологию и т.д.). По синтаксису всё вроде бы правильно, явных ошибок не вижу, в остальных частях кода всё в порядке, API тоже введен нормально, но не происходит то что нужно, бот отправляет сообщение, но без кнопок.
> '''

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(
    func=lambda call: call.data in ['Fiz-Mat', 'Mat-Inf', 'Chem-Bio', 'Hist-Geo', 'InIaz-Hist', 'InIaz-Geo'])
def comb_answer(call):
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    if call.data == 'Fiz-Mat':
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,
                         'Твой выбор Физика - Математика, вот список ресурсов по которым ты можешь подготовиться:',
                         reply_markup=keyboard)
        button1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='YouTube плейлист по Математике',
                                             url='https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLGfOjbqAzLPFiGi2i91q7w23TL-kWNcOC')
        button2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='YouTube плейлист по Физике',
                                             url='https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLGfOjbqAzLPGFzCQ3Bms01TSRyGBigasQ')
        keyboard.row(button1, button2)

    elif call.data == 'Mat-Inf':
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,
                         'Твой выбор Математика - Информатика, вот список ресурсов по которым ты можешь подготовиться:',
                         reply_markup=keyboard)
        button1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='YouTube плейлист по Математике',
                                             url='https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLGfOjbqAzLPFiGi2i91q7w23TL-kWNcOC')
        button2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='YouTube плейлист по Информатике',
                                             url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kGZiH0q62Ec&list=PLQxlbwbStGzvDdewx6z_ekEes3Zkkt2Hr')
        keyboard.row(button1, button2)

    elif call.data == 'Chem-Bio':
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,
                         'Твой выбор Химия - Биология, вот список ресурсов по которым ты можешь подготовиться:',
                         reply_markup=keyboard)
        button1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='YouTube плейлист по Химии',
                                             url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uoEiCVtcLTs&list=PLAepylbifqNrBhRyKcv6jWHUdPY-jLncg')
        button2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='YouTube плейлист по Биологии',
                                             url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xveTo2cqKZs&list=PLAepylbifqNpml9VS1qJkcM4OwLAnggsX')
        keyboard.row(button1, button2)

    elif call.data == 'Hist-Geo':
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,
                         'Твой выбор История-География, вот список ресурсов по которым ты можешь подготовиться:',
                         reply_markup=keyboard)
        button1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='YouTube плейлист по Истории',
                                             url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IcwA0wg-HI&list=PLAepylbifqNqYIEME1x8b0v8IFgUvcIpi')
        button2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='YouTube плейлист по Географии',
                                             url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PMvLzlSgJ5Q&list=PLAepylbifqNrfwlfp5Nmh48T0ahPKyuBy')
        keyboard.row(button1, button2)

    elif call.data == 'InIaz-Hist':
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,
                         'Твой выбор Английский язык-История, вот список ресурсов по которым ты можешь подготовиться:',
                         reply_markup=keyboard)
        button1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='YouTube плейлист по Английскому языку',
                                             url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NzfCJ8-rs6I&list=PLNPI0jsb5Taqho5Cw65r2KWXwF3jUz5lB')
        button2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='YouTube плейлист по Истории',
                                             url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IcwA0wg-HI&list=PLAepylbifqNqYIEME1x8b0v8IFgUvcIpi')
        keyboard.row(button1, button2)

    elif call.data == 'InIaz-Geo':
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,
                         'Твой выбор Иностранный язык-География, вот список ресурсов по которым ты можешь подготовиться:',
                         reply_markup=keyboard)
        button1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='YouTube плейлист по Английскому языку',
                                             url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NzfCJ8-rs6I&list=PLNPI0jsb5Taqho5Cw65r2KWXwF3jUz5lB')
        button2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='YouTube плейлист по Географии',
                                             url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PMvLzlSgJ5Q&list=PLAepylbifqNrfwlfp5Nmh48T0ahPKyuBy')
        keyboard.row(button1, button2)

    elif call.data == 'Basic-theme':
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,
                         'Для подготовки к основным предметам:', reply_markup=keyboard)
        button1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='YouTube плейлист по Математической грамотности',
                                             url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y1hsnH6zIiE&list=PLAepylbifqNoQPU6iMviAT_zp8LVPAfcs')
        button2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='YouTube плейлист по Грамотности чтения',
                                             url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PIx3QEWSCZA&list=PLAepylbifqNqxUCaiA6KGAD1uu8MJR5uY')
        button3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Сборка плейлистов по Истории Казахстана',
                                             url='https://www.youtube.com/@DostyqBilim/playlists?view=50&sort=dd&shelf_id=4')
        keyboard.row(button1, button2, button3)
```

'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно функцию bot.send_message() поместить после функции "keyboard.row"

Comment: А так же у вы не присвоили значение клавиатурам,к примеру :
keyboard1 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()